# Looking for good indexing and sparse matrix methods to create a matrix from existing one

Tags: python, numpy, performance, vectorization, sparse-matrix

I have a large numpy array A of shape M*3, whose elements of each row are unique, non-negative integers ranging from 0 to N - 1.  In fact, each row corresponds to a triangle in my finite element analysis.

For example, M=4, N=5, and a matrix A looks like the following

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 4],
       [3, 2, 4]])
```

Now, I need to construct another array B of size M*N, such that

```
B[m,n] = 1 if n is in A[m], or else 0
```

The corresponding B for the exemplary A above would be

```
1 1 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 1
```

A loop-based code would be

```py
B = np.zeros((M,N))
for m in range(M):
  for n in B[m]:
    B[m,n]=1
```

But since I have large M and N (of scale 10^6 for each),  how can I use good Numpy indexing techniques to accelerate this process? Besides, I feel that sparse matrix techniques are also needed since M * N data of 1 byte is about 10**12, namely 1 000 G.

In general, I feel using numpy's vectorization techniques, such as indexing and broadcasting, look more like an ad-hoc, error-prone activity relying on quite a bit of street smarts (or called art, if you prefer). Are there any programming language efforts that can systematically convert your loop-based code to a high-performance vectorized version?

Comment: Advanced indexing is quite expressive in `numpy` and needs to be learned thoroughly: `A[np.arange(M)[:,None], idx] = 1`, with *A* the result array, *idx* the indices array. [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/) can trivially JIT compile your solution. If the result array is filled with >50% non-zweo elements sparse matrices wouldn't be smaller.

Comment: Modern libraries like `pytorch` or `jax` have additional functions for common operations that are simpler to use. In `pytorch` you have [`scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html): `result.scatter_(dim=1, index=idx, value=1)`, with *result*, *idx* `torch.tensor`.

Comment: I forgot `np.put_along_axis(A, idx, 1, 1)` exists in `numpy`.

Comment: "*A loop-based code would be*" is it ```B``` instead of ```A``` in your loop based code?

Comment: Just to be bit clear what @MichaelSzczesny wrote: ```B = np.zeros((M,N)) ; B[np.arange(M)[:,None],A] = 1```

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Could you elaborate on "numba can trivially JIT compile your solution. "? I have felt numba frequently gives me compilation errors.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Also, do you mind explaining a bit your magic line, as an answer, maybe?

Comment: Dense matrices are not a good idea here because of the memory space. 10**12 is not 100 G but 1000 G. Because each item takes 8 bytes, this require 8000 GB: far more RAM that what any (realistic) computing machine have so far. Even it it would fit, the matrix will be too big to be read/written quickly (RAM is slow, storage devices are slower). Sparse matrices are a good idea but there are many kind of them designed for specific purposes because there is no 1 kind to rule them all. THus, you should tell us more about the purpose of such a matrix so we can help you further (eg. usage&sparsity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can directly create a sparse csr-matrix from your data

As you already mentioned in your question a dense matrix consisting of uint8 values would need 1 TB. By using a sparse matrix, this can be reduced to approx. 19 MB as shown in the example bellow.

**Creating Inputs with relevant size**

This should be included in the question, as it gives a hint on the sparsity of the matrix.

```
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np

M=int(1e6)
N=int(1e6)

A=np.random.randint(low=0,high=N,size=(M,3))
```

**Creating a sparse csr-matrix**

Have a look at the [scipy-doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) or for a general overview the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)) article could also be useful.

```
#array of ones, the same size of non-zero values (3 MB if uint8)
data   =np.ones(A.size,dtype=np.uint8)

#you already have the indices, they are expected as an 1D-array (12 MB)
indices=A.reshape(-1)

#every A.shape[1], a new row beginns (4 MB)
indptr =np.arange(0,A.size+1,A.shape[1])

B=sparse.csr_matrix((data,indices,indptr),shape=(M, N))
```

Comment: Good. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73415826/how-to-covert-a-large-106-106-numpy-sparse-matrix-to-a-scipy-sparse-matrix/73416136#73416136) is an answer posted simultaneously for a related question of the same OP. Both are completing each other :) .